# linkedin api - python - get_connections()

Tags: python-2.7, linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

I am working on a simple python scraping script, I am trying to get connections from LinkedIn using their API without a redirect_uri. I worked once with some APIs, that don't require the redirect url or just https://localhost. I got the consumer_key, consumer_secret, user_secret, consumer_secret. Here's the code i am using from https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin:

```
RETURN_URL = ''
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~'


# Instantiate the developer authentication class
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                          USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                                          RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

# Pass it in to the app...
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

print application.get_profile() # works
print application.get_connections()
```

And here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getContacts.py", line 20, in <module>
    print application.get_connections()
  File "/home/imane/Projects/prjL/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linkedin/linkedin.py", line 219, in get_connections
    raise_for_error(response)
  File "/home/imane/Projects/prjL/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linkedin/utils.py", line 63, in raise_for_error
    raise LinkedInError(message)
linkedin.exceptions.LinkedInError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections: Unknown Error
```

This is my first question here, so excuse me if I didn't make it clear enough, and thank you for helping me out.

Here's what i tried with python_oauth2:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import requests
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~'

params = {}
token = oauth.Token(key=USER_TOKEN, secret=USER_SECRET)
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)

# Set our token/key parameters
params['oauth_token'] = token.key
params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key

oauth_request = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)
oauth_request.sign_request(oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)
signed_url = oauth_request.to_url()
response = requests.get(signed_url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections API calls are a restricted endpoint as of March, 2015.  It's possible you're using sample code/documentation that was written at a time when anyone could access those endpoints.  You are receiving a 403 response because your application legitimately does not have the permission required to make that request.

Comment: You're right, I created a new application and add r_contactinfo and r_fullprofile in the scope, but got (An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later). Should i apply to become a LinkedIn Partner to be granted the access? I appreciate your help.

Comment: r_fullprofile will give you the same problem as trying to access connections.  It was similarly closed down.  If you remove that scope and only use r_basicprofile, you should be fine.  Applying for the Partner Program is also an option.